# Using a DD-WRT router as a wireless ethernet hub

Tags: ethernet, dd-wrt, bridge, forwarding

As the title says, I have a DD-WRT router that I would like to use as a wireless ethernet hub. I have a machine in an RV park that is ethernet only, and I need to connect it to the internet. The park has free wifi. I would like to forward ALL packets to the park's router.

Comment: If it's Ethernet only and the router is wireless only the you need a wireless adapter on the Ethernet only machine to connect to the router

Comment: What is the exact Make/Model of the router you have?

Answer (score 2):

This can easily be achieved if you already have a wireless router running DD-WRT firmware. Just configure your router as a client bridge that connects to the parks router. The DD-WRT (your) router is configured to connect to the Parks WiFi and then bridges the connection to wired (ethernet) devices attached to the DD-WRT (your) router. It's transparent. The Park's WiFi router believes that the wired (ethernet) device is connected directly to it. If it is the park's WiFi router that is a DD-WRT router go and buy a used cheap lynksys wrt54g router. You can find em at thrift stores for like 5 bucks. Flash the lynksys router you purchased with DD-WRT firmware and configure it as described above.

Instructions and help can be found at https://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Client_Bridged - let me know if you have any questions

Answer (score 1):

There are various ways to achieve this:

If the router can be positioned close enough to the device, you can simply connect them together of course & then use the router to connect to the Park's WiFi by configuring it as a client (probably referred to as a Wi-Fi extender) instead of an access point.

Alternatively, you could buy a device that is capable of being configured as a Wi-Fi extender but that has at least one ethernet input too. There are plenty of devices that will do this, try looking at Edimax & TP-Link.

In either case, you need to configure the extender to log in to the Park Wi-Fi, effectively "extending" it to the wired device.